# Why is this regular expression in.NET capturing more than I intend?

Tags: .net, regex

Not sure how to title this question exactly - I'm open to suggestions. Clearly, I'm doing something wrong with my regular expression.

I'm using .NET 4.6.2 `Regex` class with the options:

```
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline
```

The input is as follows:

```
<!--malformed HTML beyond my control-->
<table summary="Profile Information" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td height="5" colspan="2" scope="row"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Profile</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" scope="row">Name: </td>
        <td align="right">Bob Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="5" colspan="2" scope="row"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Personal Information</b></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" scope="row">Position: </td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right">IT Director</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" scope="row">Address: </td>
        <td valign="bottom" align="right">1234 Main St
                    Austin, TX
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--malformed HTML beyond my control-->
```

My regular expression is as follows:

```
<tr>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>
```

I'm expecting it to match values from the table rows that have two cells defined, and skip the rows that have only a single cell defined. Furthermore, I'm expected it to capture both the property name (i.e. `Name:`, `Position:`, `Address:`) and the values associated with them.

Instead, I'm getting the following captures:

1. **Matched String**

   `<tr> 
   <td height="5" colspan="2" scope="row"></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Profile</b></font></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td valign="top" scope="row">Name: </td> 
   <td align="right">Bob Smith</td> 
   </tr>`

   **$1**

   `</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Profile</b></font></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td valign="top" scope="row">Name:`

   **$2**

   `Bob Smith`
2. **Matched String**

   `<tr> 
   <td height="5" colspan="2" scope="row"></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Personal Information</b></font></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td valign="top" scope="row">Position: </td> 
   <td valign="bottom" align="right">IT Director</td> 
   </tr>`

   **$1**

   `</td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td colspan="2" scope="row"><font size="4"><b>Personal Information</b></font></td> 
   </tr> 
   <tr> 
   <td valign="top" scope="row">Position:`

   **$2**

   `IT Director`
3. **Matched String**

   `<tr> 
   <td valign="top" scope="row">Address: </td> 
   <td valign="bottom" align="right">1234 Main St 
   Austin, TX 
   </td> 
   </tr>`

   **$1**

   `Address:`

   **$2**

   `1234 Main St
   Austin, TX`

I apologize for not being able to put the results into a more succinct format. Tables aren't allowed for questions apparently.

#### What I think might be going wrong

It seems to me that one of my dot matchers is matching more than I want it to match. I've told them to be non-greedy `(.*?)`, so I'm a little confused why they seem to be matching beyond the first encountered ending tag.

As far as I can tell, this should never be in any match:

```
<tr>
<td height="5" colspan="2" scope="row"></td>
</tr>
```

Yet, it appears in the first matched string.

What am I missing? How should this be achieved?

Let me know if there is any additional information required for this question.

P.S. I've been using http://regexstorm.net/tester to attempt and debug the issue.

Comment: Please explain why you are using an improper tool to parse HTML. I understand you have access to code, so why not use something like HtmlAgilityPack?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Because the HTML is invalid, and can't be read by a DOM reader. I have no control over the input text. This portion is fine, but other bits of the entire HTML file throw HtmlAgilityPack for a loop.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I suppose I could try to extract just this table and feed it to HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I will close this one as the solution is clear: tempered greedy token. `.*?` do not guarantee the shortest matches between strings. Either use `[^<>]*` when inside an element node, or use `(?:(?!<td\b).)*?` when you want to match between `<td>` and next `<td>` in order not to overmatch. Adapt as per your needs.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've never heard of tempered greedy token, but it does seem like it could solve the issue. Thanks for bringing to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-greedy matches won’t affect the behaviour of taking the first match. If there’s a greedy match at a given position, there will also be a non-greedy match at that position. You can hack it by not matching any `</td>`s:

```
<tr>\s*<td.*?>((?:(?!</td>).)*?)</td>\s*<td.*?>((?:(?!</td>).)*?)</td>\s*</tr>
```

But I’d actually do it in two steps, by first matching:

```
<tr>(.*?)</tr>
```

and then inside each of those, checking the rest of the simpler expression.

Comment: I'm not getting the desired output from your first expression either, but I think it's the right idea, and just needs some slight tweaking. It seems to use the tempered greedy token approach mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I came up with this, based on your answer: `<tr>\s*<td(?:(?!</td>).)*>((?:(?!</td>).)+)</td>\s*<td(?:(?!</td>).)*>((?:(?!</td>).)+)</td>\s*</tr>` I'm going to try and apply some of the further instruction from @WiktorStribiżew from [his answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/1195273)

Comment: @crush: Oh, yep, I missed those `.*`s. Sorry. (And it is the same approach, but note that “tempered greedy token” isn’t a standard term or something I’d ever call it….)

Answer (score 1):

Try .*? Instead of .*
This should disable the greedy look ahead

Try this:

```
string regTR = @"<tr>(.+?)</tr>";
Regex ItemRegex = new Regex(regTR, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

var matches = ItemRegex.Matches(readText);
foreach (Match ItemMatch in matches)
{
   string outer = ItemMatch.Groups[0].Value;
   string innerRegex = @"<td.*?>(.*?)</td>\s*<td.*?>(.*?)</td>";

   Match match = Regex.Match(outer, innerRegex, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

   if (match.Success)
   {
        string inner1 = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string inner2 = match.Groups[2].Value;                    
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what I was already doing?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you already used ? in your regex. Give me a second I try to reproduce your issue

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Good answer showing how to do it in multiple steps, but I elected to use the single regexp approach shown above. +1